# Web Application Web Config run time error

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Im working with Visual Studio 2012 Web Forms the website is starting normally when i open it from  local server  but when i move the files to GoDaddy hosting into httpdocs this error appears

```
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 

    Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".


    <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

    <configuration>
        <system.web>
            <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        </system.web>
    </configuration>
    Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.


    <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

    <configuration>
        <system.web>
            <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
        </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is throwing an exception that you can't see. Change your code to mode="Off" as the message indicates. Long term I would recommend using a logging tool like ELMAH so you can see the exceptions and give end users the friendly page. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx